# When loading data, there is a display that cannot be converted to a related type. What should I do?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

```
data_root = 'E:/ngsimclean/data/Next_Generation_Simulation__NGSIM__Vehicle_Trajectories_and_Supporting_Data.csv'
        with open(pra_file_path, 'r') as reader:
        # print(train_file_path)
        content = np.array([x.strip().split(' ') for x in reader.readlines()]).astype(float)
        now_dict = {}
```

The error displayed is as follows:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,003.073'
```

The above is part of the code. Due to the large amount of data, I cannot locate where this data is.

Comment: Somewhere in your text file, there is 1,003.073 string which cannot be converted to float due to the comma. 

You can remove the comma to see if it works, but if it happens multiple times in the file, I recommend to add .replace(',','') to remove the commas when reading the lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I've already add this order. Just like this:  content = np.array([x.replace(',','').strip().split(' ') for x in reader.readlines()])   . But after adding this command, the problem still occurs. What is the reason for this? What do I have to do about it?  Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: If you open the file to search for 1,003.073 and manually remove the comma, do you still get the same ValueError?